# msession not defined

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am trying to run this example program - http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/1.x/snmpbulk.html

I am on Mac OS X, and I installed pysnmp by -

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install pysnmp
```

Now when I run the program I get -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysnmptest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysnmp import msession
ImportError: cannot import name msession
```

---

### UPDATE:

seems like pysnmp 4.x doesn't have msession, so I tried  http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/4.x/v3arch/index.html

and now I get -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysnmptest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysnmp.proto.rfc3412 import MsgAndPduDispatcher
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pysnmp.smi import builder, instrum
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pysnmp.smi import error
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/error.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyasn1.error import PyAsn1Error
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.error
```

The webpage also says they have dependencies on third-party libraries -

> Latest PySNMP releases (4.x and later)
>   depend on the following:
>
> ASN.1 library for Python used for
>   handling ASN.1 objects Python
>   Cryptography Toolkit used for SNMP
>   message authentication and encryption

How do I install them? and would it better to install from the tarball from webpage directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which version of `pysmnp` did you install? The example you're trying to run seems to be suited for the 1.x version of `pysnmp`.

Here I've found [examples for the **newest** 4.x version](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/4.x/v1arch/index.html). Note they don't use `msession` so I guess it was removed.

---

**EDIT**: Looks like now you have to install `pyasn1` from [here](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/)...
I don't use OSX so I don't know what's the better method for installing software on it. On ubuntu I just did `apt-get install python-pysnmp` and the whole thing was installed.

Answer (score 0):

`pyasn1` has been depended by pysnmp. So you could just type:

```
from pyasn1.error import PyAsn1Error
```